# Avoid button styling its content in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating an iOS app using Apple's SwiftUI framework. As I need to detect if the user taps on a specific area of the screen, I obviously use a button.

The problem is that the area contains an Image and a Text, and as the button automatically gives its content the blue color, the image is also colored, so instead of being an Image it's just a blue rounded rectangle.

It is said that an image is worth a thousand words, and as I'm not good at explaining, here you have a graphic demonstration of what happens:

**Outside the button (without button styling)**
[image: without button styling]

**Inside the button (with button styling)**
[image: with button styling]

This happens because the button is adding `.foregroundColor(.blue)` to the image.

How can I avoid/disable the button adding style to its components?

**EDIT**: This is my button code:

*ContentView.swift*:

```
Button(action: {/* other code */}) {
                    PackageManagerRow(packageManager: packageManagersData[0])
                }
```

*PackageManagerRow.swift*:

```
struct PackageManagerRow : View {
    var packageManager : PackageManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(packageManager.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 42.0, height: 42.0)
                Text(verbatim: packageManager.name)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .opacity(0)
            }.padding(.bottom, 0)
            Divider()
                .padding(.top, -3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create the button.

Comment: @Fogmeister of course, see my edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is from the rendering mode for the image you are using.

Where you have `Image("Cydia logo")` (or whatever).

You should be setting the rendering mode like...

```
Image("Cydia Logo").renderingMode(.original)
```

Comment: When I add this method to my Image it gives me an error on the part where I set the image size:

 'Double' is not convertible to 'Length?' (aka 'Optional<CGFloat>')

Comment: @iAlex11 Are you adding the rendering mode after adding the size?

Comment: Ohh ok thanks I see. Could you please explain why does this happen? Thanks and sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 10):

You can also add a `PlainButtonStyle()` to your button to avoid iOS style behaviors.

Something like that with your example :

```
Button(action: {/* other code */}) {
                    PackageManagerRow(packageManager: packageManagersData[0])
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 4):

If you are managing yourself all the customisation of a button, then using the `.buttonStyle(.plain)` is good but not enough, as said in its documentation, it only disables some styling, not all of them.

i.e. presssed would still be managed by SwiftUI.

[image]

If you want 0 modification from SwiftUI on your Button, you have to create a Custom Style that does **nothing**

```swift
struct NoButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        return configuration.label
    }
}

// Then use
// .buttonStyle(NoButtonStyle())
// And voila
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to not use a `Button` wrapper, but instead use [`tapAction` directly on the Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3336957-tapaction) to trigger your action when the image is pressed

Answer (score 1):

```
HStack {
    Button(action: {
        print("Tapped")
     }, label: {
         Image("Logo").renderingMode(.original) // Add Rendering Mode
     })
    Text("Cydia")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A button with an icon! How original .
If you are dealing with SF symbols then the following will do fine:

```
    Button(action: addItem) {
        Text(Image(systemName: "plus").renderingMode(.original))
            +
            Text("This is Plus")
    }
    .font(.system(size: 42))
```

The limitation of the option above is you don't have control over `Image`'s size. So for custom images the following is more appropriate:

```
    Button(action: addItem) {
        Label(
            title: { Text("Label").font(.system(size: 40)) }, // Any font you like
            icon: { Image(systemName: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis") // Both custom and system images, i.e. `Image("Cydia logo")`
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 42, height: 42) // Any size you like
                .padding() // Any padding you need
                } // and etc.
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the style `.plain` to your button to avoid overlay color.

```
// Before
Button(...)
```

[image: with button styling]

```
// After
Button(...)
.buttonStyle(.plain) // Remove the overlay color (blue) for images inside Button
```

- `.plain` button style, that doesn’t style or decorate its content while idle, but may apply a visual effect to indicate the pressed, focused, or enabled state of the button.

[image: without button styling]

Another solution is to custom the style with `ButtonStyle`

like: `struct MyButtonStyle:ButtonStyle { }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the original image by adding `.renderingMode(.original)` right after your image declaration.

```
Image("your_image_name")
    .renderingMode(.original)
```

Comment: Nice copy paste from the accepted answer!

Comment: mine don’t have spelling mistakes

Comment: @FatehKhan I reported this answer, you are being racist to new users and you should not copy paste answers, that is just embarrassing...