# Putting an Image() from url inside an HStack inside of Button inside of List makes it go black

Tags: swiftui

I've been trying to make a List of buttons, and when it gets clicked, it calls some code, I also need some 'thumbnails' to go along with every button, so I made a HStack for each button and put it all on a List, now the thumbnail doesn't render, BTW, it renders system images and local assets just fine, it's just the images grabbed from the network

you can just copy-paste this into ContentView.swift to reproduce it

```swift
import SwiftUI

func artwork() -> Image
{
    let art = "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    if let url = URL(string: art), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data)
    {
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    }
    else
    {
        return Image(systemName: "book")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        List
        {
            Button(action: {...my code...})
            {
                HStack
                {
                    artwork()
                }
... some other info
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is to put the artwork function in a separate class (Model) and to work with an ObjectBinding. There is also no caching functionality which could result in a bad performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is similar to [Avoid button styling its content in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931932/avoid-button-styling-its-content-in-swiftui)

You just have to add `.renderingMode(.original)` to your `Image` like so:

```
func artwork() -> Image
{
    let art = "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    if let url = URL(string: art), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data)
    {
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    }
    else
    {
        return Image(systemName: "book")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        List
        {
            Button(action: {})
            {
                HStack
                {
                    artwork().renderingMode(.original)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```